# check if neo4j instance is already running

Tags: java, neo4j

How can i check if neo4j instance is already running.

I am using Embedded Neo4j Database and starting neo4j using :

```
GraphDatabaseService graphdb = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase("C:/GraphDB");
```

And finally shutting down

```
graphdb.shutdown();
```

Now what i want to do is if neo4j instance is already running and a new request is made to access the database i want new request to wait until previous finishes.

How can i do it or can i check if the instance is already running????

Answer (score 0):

You doesn't need to serialize access to embedded graph db. All you need to do is created the embedded database in [ServletContextLister.contextInitialized()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) and shut it down in ServletContextLister.contextDestroyed.

Answer (score 0):

Well,
you could try to open the DB, and you will get an exception if the store files are already locked by a competing database.